# NodeJS how to get data by entering specific value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an application where I want to list a bunch of Artists by letter. So for example if I enter the letter "L" - the application should return all artists from my DB with the letter "L". I'm pretty new to NodeJS, so maybe someone can help me out?

my routes.js:

```
server.get('/i/artists/:letter', myartists.getArtistByLetter);
```

and my artists.js:

```
exports.getArtistByLetter = function(req, res, next){

   var where;

   if(req.query == '0-9') // not sure about req.query, probably wrong???
   {
      where = ["formated_name RLIKE '^[0-9#]' AND artist_parent_id = 0 "];
   }
   else  
   {
      where = ["formated_name LIKE '"+req.query+"%' AND artist_parent_id = 0"];
   }    

   db.artist.findAll({ 
      where: where, 
      attributes: ['artist_id', ['formated_name', 'name'], 'uuid', 'slug']
    }, {raw: true})
    .success(function(artist){
       res.json({data: artist});
   });  

}
```

After entering `http://localhost:2100/i/artists/l` this returns `{"data":[]}`...

so, any suggestions? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To acces `letter` parameter you have to write `req.params.letter` instead of `req.query`.

Take a look at the answer of [how to hande a get request with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29582035/3790486).

On this url: `http://localhost:2100/i/artists/l` the `req.params.letter` wil have the value `l`.